# removing words from a title

Tags: jquery

```
  $("p.author").text(function() {
     return $(this).text().replace(/(By|on)/g, '');
  });
```

I found this on an earlier post which describes how to remove the word "By" from an element 'p.author'

what I want to do is remove the a word from a title

something like this?

```
  v = $('.datarow .location').attr('title').replace(/,/g,'');
  $("span.name").attr('title').(v);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.datarow .location').attr('title', function(index, attr){
  return attr.replace(/,/g,'');
});
```

`.attr()` accepts a function as a second parameter, and gives us the old value of attr as it's second argument.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/83WLm/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p.author").text(function() {
 return $.trim($(this).text()).replace(/^(By|on)/gi, '');
});?

/gi => means ignore case, greedy
^ => means starting
$.trim()  jquery trim characters
```

Demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/wwmy9/

Can you post the HTML code as well?
I'll modify my fiddle answer after seeing them.

Careful on replacing the "on" it might remove the "on" from Ronnie

Comment: should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks ahren, I were planning to put it as answer.